# Python Crashing with error with Nested For Loop: ValueError: Buffer has wrong number of dimensions (expected 1, got 0)

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following nested for loop. This purpose is to create an Adjacency matrix (295x295) from my data set which is (658,295) in size.

When I run this code, I get the error in the title, and I am not sure how to solve for this. Any help is appreciated.

```
gensum = np.sum(data)
p=len(gensum) 
W = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros([p,p]))


for i in range(np.shape(data)[1]):
    for k in range(np.shape(data)[1]): 
        temp = data.iloc[:,[k,i+1]]
        temp['new'] = temp.iloc[:,0] + temp.iloc[:,1] 
        temp['new']=temp['new'].map({0:0,1:0,2:1})
        assign = np.sum(temp['new'])
        W.iat[k,i+1] = assign
        W.iat[i+1,k] = assign
```

Comment: Hard to say without a knowing the data you are looping over. Could you provide a fully reproducible demo of the code together with sample data that produces the error?

Comment: Are you sure you mean to iterate over the same dimension of your data twice? `range(np.shape(data)[1]`

Comment: Yeah. Data is 300 variables along the columns, and 160 records. The variables are binary indicating presence in the record. I am attempting to create an adjacency matrix that shows when one variable is present with another, and sum that up for each record.